# How to set N amount of consecutive bits in a byte, starting from LSB?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to set an N amount of bits in a byte (byte always starts as 0) and store it using a pointer. Imagine:

```
void SetBits(uint8_t bytesToSet, uint8_t* var) {}
```

How would I go about implementing this (using C)?

Comment: Tip: `0b10000` minus `1` is `0b1111`.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a free coding service.  Show us what you have tried and tell why the result is not what you expected.  Then we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where should that N bits be set? To the left, to the right?

If you want to have those N bits to the right, your function should look like this:

```
void SetBits(uint8_t bitsToSet, uint8_t* var)
{
    if (bitsToSet < 8)
        *var = (1 << bitsToSet) - 1;
    else {*var = 0; *var = ~(*var);}
}
```

For an example, for the call `SetBits(5,&a)`, variable `a` will hold the value `0b00011111`.

Comment: sorry you are right. there should be no `+1` there.

Comment: Alternative to `*var = 0; *var = ~(*var);` --> `*var = -1;` or `*var = -1u` or `*var = 255u;`

Comment: You should name the argument `bitsToSet` instead of `bytesToSet`

Comment: Sorry i just copied the function declaration from his question. Editing now.